# Handling exception from Rails engine in the app that it's mounted in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I have a Rails engine that handles some generic behaviour, and I want to ship that with a different branding and styles for each customer. So I create the main app as a normal Rails application, with the customers assets available, and mount the engine as a gem inside of that app. Now suppose that I want to present any errors arising from the engine also using the customer styles. The engine doesn't have access to the customer-specific assets (because it's purely generic), so I have to handle those errors inside the application code itself.

This is what I tried:

In the engine:

```rb
module MyEngine
  class EngineException < RuntimeError
  end

  ...

  // in engine application code
  raise EngineException('oops') if (bad_thing)
end
```

In the containing application:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from MyEngine::EngineException do |e|
    render 'error/error'
  end
end
```

Rails swallows this without complaining, but the `rescue_from` block never gets triggered. Instead, I just see the generic stacktrace page because `EngineException` was not caught.

So I assume that there's something else I need to do to trap errors arising from the engine and handle them in the app itself, but I've searched in vain so far.

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever got an answer to this, but the issue is that your engine's ApplicationController class is not equal to the main ApplicationController class, it's actually MyEngine::ApplicationController so that method is isolated from the main ApplicationController.